# Why is space added between UIButtons?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
   let mostRead = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: tableView.frame.origin.y + tableView.frame.height, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 160))
    mostRead.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "mostread"), for: .normal)
    mostRead.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.goToMostRead(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    innerView.addSubview(mostRead)
    
    let videoTitles = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: mostRead.frame.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 160))
    videoTitles.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "videotitles"), for: .normal)
    videoTitles.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.goToVideoTitles(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    innerView.addSubview(videoTitles)
    
    
    let audioTitles = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: videoTitles.frame.maxY, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: 160))
    audioTitles.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "audiotitles"), for: .normal)
    audioTitles.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.goToAudioTitles(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    innerView.addSubview(audioTitles)
```

Space gets added between the UI Buttons. If you notice in the picture, there's a lot of space between each image even though I specified no space between images. Does anyone know why that's happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `frame.height` instead of `frame.size.height`

Comment: @Will didn't work

Comment: Try `videoTitles.frame.maxY` instead of `videoTitles.frame.origin.y + videoTitles.frame.size.height`

Comment: @Will didn't work

Comment: If you print `videoTitles.frame.height` before calling `audioTitles`, do you get 160?

Comment: This is a little confusing... What is `mostRead`? Is it an image view? A label? Something else?

Comment: they are UIButtons

Comment: It's still a bit confusing... are the blue and red rounded-rectangle that you've shown the actual **images** that you are setting for the buttons? Add these lines: `mostRead.backgroundColor = .green` ... `videoTitles.backgroundColor = .blue` ... `audioTitles.backgroundColor = .red` then run your code and post a new screen-cap.

Comment: As a side note... why are you not using auto-layout?

Comment: @DonMag Please see updated question

Comment: @LouisaScheinost - ok... as you can now see, your **buttons** do not have vertical space between them. However you have them configured, the **images** you are setting results in padding around them image.

Comment: @DonMag I think that's how the UIButton formats the images. The images have no padding at all

Comment: @LouisaScheinost - no, the default image view in a button does not round corners. Edit your post with the original images you are using - or at least one of them.

Comment: Are these inside a tableview?

Comment: This would be a perfect time to use Xcode's view hierarchy debugger, which would let you see exactly why things are laid out as they are and probably lead you to the exact reason: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add it with stackView and auto layout like this:
first set your object under your controller class:

```
let buttonmostRead: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "mostRead"), for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return button
}()

let buttonvideoTitles: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "videoTitles"), for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return button
}()

let buttonaudiotitles: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .red
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "audiotitles"), for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return button
}()
```

after that in viewDiLoad set staclView an constraints:

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [buttonmostRead, buttonvideoTitles, buttonaudiotitles])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.spacing = 8
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 466).isActive = true
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

to set space between button, change stackView spacing...
and this is the result
[image]

I put stackView in the center of the view but you can place them wherever you want by changing the constraints...